# Bundle python script and dependencies into a single file

Tags: python, scripting, egg

I have a few script that had their own copy of a some functions, so I extracted these functions to a module and had the scripts import the function. These script are to be copied over to a bunch of linux servers and executed. When the scripts worked standalone, I would simply copy the files over to the servers and execute "python  ".

I have a central management server that will copy and run the scripts on the different servers.

I've done some reading on python eggs, but could use some advice on method to go for. The way I do it today is to copy and simply run the python script. As this works fine, I was thinking maybe there is a way to bundle the scripts themselves with the (in-house) module they're dependent on, copy the bundle over to the servers and execute them. Don't see why I would need to install anything using "pip".

Now, what kind of setup would you guys recommend? Should I maybe build eggs on my local computer, and have the management server copy the egg file over to the servers? I would prefer to copy everything the server need over from the management server, instead of having the servers pull down dependencies themselves, so that I won't have to punch more holes all the firewalls. Since eggs typically need to pull down dependencies, maybe eggs are not the way to go?

Most of my servers are running python 2.6, but I do have some running python 2.4 and 3.2.

Greetings,
Kenneth

Answer (score 8):

You might want to consider looking at Twitter's PEX library which can create executable files from python packages: https://pex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatispex.html

> .pex files are just carefully constructed zip files with a #!/usr/bin/env python and special `__main.py__`

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2016**: [wagon](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/wagon) helps building wheel packages with dependencies for offline installation.

---

For simple projects keeping all source together in one folder and copying it as a whole is good enough.  You can use [git](http://git-scm.com/) to push your code to a central repository and pull it to your server, without building any packages.  [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) and [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) are two tools that can help you automate the deployment process.  (For example, remotely run `git pull` and delete all your `pyc` files).

If you have shared dependencies between projects, [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [wheels](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are the modern alternatives to eggs:

> You can create a simple bundle that contains all of the dependencies
> you wish to install using.
>
> ```
> $ tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/wheelhouse-XXXXX)
> $ pip wheel -r requirements.txt --wheel-dir=$tempdir
> $ cwd=`pwd`
> $ (cd "$tempdir"; tar -cjvf "$cwd/bundled.tar.bz2" *)
> ```
>
> Once you have a bundle, you can then uninstall it using:
>
> ```
> $ tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/wheelhouse-XXXXX)
> $ (cd $tempdir; tar -xvf /path/to/bundled.tar.bz2)
> $ pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --upgrade --no-index --use-wheel --no-deps $tempdir/*
> ```

(From [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles))

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice. I'll continue keeping all the sources in a single zip-file until I see the need to share the dependencies between projects.