# How to remove the mousewheel default zoom on opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm looking to remove the default zoom behavior while scrolling up and down with the mouse wheel on OpenCV. I set a mouse callback method (defined below) in order to override this behavior without success :

```
import cv2

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global index

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEWHEEL :
        if flags > 0:
            index += 1
        elif flags < 0:
            index -= 1
        index %= length

cv2.namedWindow('window', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setMouseCallback('window', mouse_callback)
cv2.imshow('window', path)
```

Has anyone succeeded in removing that default behavior ?

Comment: Looking for the exact thing right now!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it doesn't seem to be possible the easy way because opencv-python uses the HighGui by default which was/is mainly intended for debugging.

**Solution 1**

That's what I did and it works. You need to rebuild the [opencv-python](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) project yourself and make some changes in the included opencv in the file [window_QT.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp). In there you find the function `DefaultViewPort::wheelEvent` in which you can remove the `scaleView` function call.

**Solution 2**

You need to rebuild opencv-python as well and choose the GTK instead of the QT ui. I got that suggestion from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/191299/how-to-disable-zoom-via-mouse-wheel-in-opencv-window/).

**How to build opencv-python?**

How to build the opencv-python project is described [here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python). You mainly need to `git clone` and run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`. Be aware that solutions 1 and 2 only work on the machines having the altered opencv library (unless you look into [packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237312/bundle-python-script-and-dependencies-into-a-single-file)).

**Solution 3**

You use a completely other library for displaying your images/frames, like [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) or [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news).

**Solution 4**

This depends on your use case but with [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io) you can "[Get exclusive access to a device](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-exclusive-access-to-a-device)". Meaning, only your application can receive events from a specific device like mouse. There might be an option as well to only ego-grab certain events if you dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Got the idea from another discussion regarding cv2 window

I'm not sure what it did, but maybe it forced cv2 into using the GTK backend instead of QT.